# iOS embedd page thumbnails in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, thumbnails

I need to embed thumbnails in large hq PDF files, which I create using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile and UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage and drawing text and images on them.

Does anyone know, how to embed page thumbs?

Ciao, Arno

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a thumbnail from a PDF, then you could use the code below. This code writes it to disk. It's easy to change it so that the method returns the image.

```
- (void)createPDFThumbnailForFile:(NSString *)theFilename {
    if (!theFilename) {return;}
    @try {
        NSString *path = [FileInfo fullPathForFile:theFilename];
        NSURL *pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        CFURLRef pdfFileRef = (__bridge CFURLRef) pdfFileUrl;
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfFileRef);
        CGPDFPageRef page;
        CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 100); // thumbnail size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        UIImage *thumbnailImage;
    //    NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
        //we only want the first page
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);
            // Grab the first PDF page
            page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
            CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);
            // And apply the transform.
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

            // Create the new UIImage from the context
            thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
        NSString *pngPath = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".pdf" withString:@".png"];
    //    [@"test" writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DebugLog(@"Could not write thumbnail to : %@ /n --> %@", theFileToSave, exception.description);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I know how to *draw* thumbs, but I need them to be embedded as page thumbnails in the pdf.